# Xcode Storyboard: Button image gets stretched with autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an issue where my storyboard subviews aren't sizing properly in the simulator. For some reason,

1) the image for the settings button (on the top right, marked with the arrow) is getting stretched
2) the text in my black label is getting cut off

Simulator:

[image]

Storyboard:

[image]

I'm using autolayout. Perhaps I'm missing a constraint? but it looks like everything is snapped to the blue lines. What's going on??

Comment: I think you are missing a constraint for the height of the image. You can also pin the aspect ratio to be 1:1 and that should work also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have set the width constraint of your image view absolutely. That's fine, but you didn't (as far as I can tell) also set its height constraint, so it adopts the height of the original image, which is much taller.

Comment: oooooooo let me try it out

Comment: The exact results will also depend (in a possibly confusing way) on the image view's content mode...

Comment: And if you want to make the button bigger with the screen size use 'Aspect Ratio' constraint.